# exim + courier + squirrelmail mail delivery in wrong directories

Tags: smtp, imap, exim, mail-transport-agent, courier

I just installed an E-Mailserver using exim for SMTP, courier(-imap) for fetching mails via IMAPv4 and squirrelmail as web client for the end user. Everything works fine. But when I sent an E-Mail to adress on my server, it is stored in the file `/var/mail/<UNIX-USERNAME>`, but not in the maildirs I created in `/home/<UNIX-USERNAME>/Maildir`

I am also able to log into squirrelmail. Sending mails also works. The copy of the sent E-Mail is stored in the right directoy. So, how do I tell exim to deliver incoming E-Mails to `/home/<UNIX-USERNAME>/Maildir/INBOX`?

Edit: My exim config (removed comments for better view)

```
primary_hostname = renamed-gaming.com
domainlist local_domains = @
domainlist relay_to_domains =
hostlist   relay_from_hosts = localhost

acl_smtp_rcpt = acl_check_rcpt
acl_smtp_data = acl_check_data

#tls_certificate = /etc/ssl/exim.crt
#tls_privatekey = /etc/ssl/exim.pem

daemon_smtp_ports = 25 : 465 : 587
tls_on_connect_ports = 465

never_users = root

host_lookup = *
rfc1413_hosts = *
rfc1413_query_timeout = 5s

ignore_bounce_errors_after = 2d

timeout_frozen_after = 7d

begin acl

acl_check_rcpt:

  accept  hosts = :
          control = dkim_disable_verify

  deny    message       = Restricted characters in address
          domains       = +local_domains
          local_parts   = ^[.] : ^.*[@%!/|]

  deny    message       = Restricted characters in address
          domains       = !+local_domains
          local_parts   = ^[./|] : ^.*[@%!] : ^.*/\\.\\./

  accept  local_parts   = postmaster
          domains       = +local_domains

  require verify        = sender

  accept  hosts         = +relay_from_hosts
          control       = submission
          control       = dkim_disable_verify

  accept  authenticated = *
          control       = submission
          control       = dkim_disable_verify

  require message = relay not permitted
          domains = +local_domains : +relay_to_domains

  require verify = recipient

  accept

acl_check_data:

  accept

begin routers

dnslookup:
  driver = dnslookup
  domains = ! +local_domains
  transport = remote_smtp
  ignore_target_hosts = 0.0.0.0 : 127.0.0.0/8

system_aliases:
  driver = redirect
  allow_fail
  allow_defer
  data = ${lookup{$local_part}lsearch{/etc/aliases}}
# user = exim
  file_transport = address_file
  pipe_transport = address_pipe

userforward:
  driver = redirect
  check_local_user
# local_part_suffix = +* : -*
# local_part_suffix_optional
  file = $home/.forward
# allow_filter
  no_verify
  no_expn
  check_ancestor
  file_transport = address_file
  pipe_transport = address_pipe
  reply_transport = address_reply

localuser:
  driver = accept
  check_local_user
# local_part_suffix = +* : -*
# local_part_suffix_optional
  transport = local_delivery
  cannot_route_message = Unknown user

begin transports

remote_smtp:
  driver = smtp


local_delivery:
  driver = appendfile
  file = /var/mail/$local_part
  delivery_date_add
  envelope_to_add
  return_path_add
# group = mail
# mode = 0660

address_pipe:
  driver = pipe
  return_output

address_file:
  driver = appendfile
  delivery_date_add
  envelope_to_add
  return_path_add

address_reply:
  driver = autoreply


# Address or Domain    Error       Retries
# -----------------    -----       -------

*                      *           F,2h,15m; G,16h,1h,1.5; F,4d,6h

begin rewrite

begin authenticators
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Exim, you have to configure the transport for the local delivery router correctly. It's apparently now using a transport that's configured to deliver to `/var/mail/$local_part`, see if you have a transport that's configured to deliver to the directory = $home/Maildir and use that.

Without knowing how your config looks like at the moment it's not possible to give more detailed information, however I think with the above hints you should be able to fix it.

Comment: solved not really my Problem. It´s the solution, right. But what I really needed was to change it to mbx mail format (Maildir format) and everything works fine...